# Tryin' hard not to give the answer away

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> I'm the real name of an action director.
>   I'm a small unit of weight.
>   Not one to lead, but I'll happily follow.
>   In a flu I don't sound right.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winging this, are you:

> ng

I'm the real name of an action director.

> John Woo, born Ng Yu-sum, the filmmaker who got going directing Kung Fu films in Hong Kong.

I'm a small unit of weight.

> ng for nanogram, a small unit of mass.

Not one to lead, but I'll happily follow.

> The Eng. Lang. is abounding with words ending in ng while its foreign to start with this.

In a flu I don't sound right.

> ng is the voiced velar nasal sound - distressing to make with a blocked nose.

Tryin' hard not to give the answer away

> n' obfuscating the ng

Comment: Yup, this is exactly it.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Newton

I'm the real name of an action director.

> A quick google search for 'action director newton' brings up Matthew Newton

I'm a small unit of weight.

> Newton is indeed a small unit of weight

Not one to lead, but I'll happily follow.

> Not sure about this one, maybe a reference to the infamous apple fall? Follow = fall low?

In a flu I don't sound right.

> Newtonian fluid

Title

> Tryin' emphasizing the 'n' which is the unit for Newton N

Comment: This actually fits the second line better than the intended answer, because I somehow forgot about the weight vs mass distinction when writing this :S

Comment: No big deal, intended answer makes more sense on the other lines. Nice riddle nonetheless!